# Plotting Interaction Terms when the moderating variable is not categorical?

Tags: interaction

For all the tutorials I've found such as this one: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/vis_interaction_effects/

The moderator variable has always been categorical like "male", "female". How do you plot if the moderating variable is non-categorical like "Number of cigarettes smoked"?  Do you group them into buckets?  If so, how would you choose the intervals of the buckets?

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate the marginal means (for regular regression) or marginal probabilities (for logistic regression) at any specific value of the moderating variable that you want.

It is common on psychological scales that measure latent constructs to do this at a standard deviation below and a standard deviation above the mean on the continuous moderator.

But, for something like cigarettes smoked, there may be specific values that are useful (one per day, however many are in a pack, however many are in two packs, etc.)